# apt-get krb5-user unmet dependencies 1.14.3+dfsg-2ubuntu1?

Tags: kerberos

I need to install krb5-user but I encounter the error below:

> krb5-user : Depends: libkrb5-3 (= 1.14.3+dfsg-2) but
>   1.14.3+dfsg-2ubuntu1 is to be installed

I don't understand what does this mean or what other apps I need to install? Please help.

uname - a returned

> Linux osboxes 4.8.0-59-generic #64-Ubuntu SMP Thu Jun 29 19:38:34 UTC 2017 
>   x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

I did a sudo apt update before install.

Regarding the software ppa, I can't remember if I added any. But here's the list reflected under Software and updates:

- http://ppa.launchpad.net/webupd8team/java/ubuntu yakkety main
- http://dl.bintray/sbt/debian/
- http://ppa.launchpad.net/rockclimb/gephi-daily/ubuntu yakkety main
- http://ppa.launchpad.net/openjdk-r/ppa/ubuntu yakkety main
- Recommended updates

Comment: It means that "krb5-user" is looking for a specific version of "libkrb5-3" but that the specific version is not available.  Can you add the outputs of `uname -a` to your question? And have you done `sudo apt update` recently?

Comment: Looks like you failed to install krb5 before from some non-Ubuntu source, and did not clean up the mess. Delete the non-Ubuntu source, and uninstall all package from that source. After you have cleaned up, installing krb5-user from the Ubuntu repositories will work.

Comment: All modern Ubuntus do not have [libkrb5-3 version 1.14.3+dfsg-2](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&searchon=names&keywords=libkrb5-3). Which Ubuntu version do you have? Have you added PPAs or third-party repositories? Please update your question with the output of `apt-cache policy krb5-user libkrb5-3`.